# How many integer-valued solutions?

Tags: combinatorics

How many integer-valued solutions are there?

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 63, x_i \ge 0, x_2 \le 9.$$

My Approach

$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 63, x_i \ge 0, x_2 \le 9.$$

$$ x_2' = x_2 - 9$$

$$ x_1 + x_2' + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 54, x_i \ge 0, x_2' \le 0 $$

... And I'm lost

Comment: your thoughts ?

Comment: @JohnBaek I am not stalking. I just see these questions pop out in the screen in a short interval, and it turns out to be you asking all these questions, and they turn out to be quite similar.

Comment: Hint: "Good = All – Bad". Count all solutions where all $x_i\ge 0$, and then subtract those where, additionally, $x_2\ge 10$.

Comment: and that's exactly what you asked one hour ago.

Comment: John Baek: Reasking the same question is very much frowned upon here. Irrespective of whether you [deleted the earlier version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625998/11619) or not. You aren't adding useful content to the site with such antics. You are littering. Consider this a warning. If a question attracts negative attention, then reposting will only make matters worse. The solution is to IMPROVE the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... and "stalking" makes sense.

You do know that you can use "star and bars" to get the number of solutions for:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=63,x_i\ge0,$$

and from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625998/how-many-integer-valued-solutions-are-there) you asked one hour ago you know how to do it for

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=63,x_i\ge 0,x_2\ge 10.,$$

Subtract the number and you will get the count for this question.